# Long-periodic sungrazers

Tags: solar-system, comets

I'm searching for long- and non-periodic sungrazing comets, like the [Kirch comet of 1680](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Comet_of_1680) and the (meanwhile destroyed) [Comet ISON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_ISON). If you know a(ny) long-/non-periodic sungrazing comet(s), let me know here, please.

I'd prefer to learn about sungrazers that are *not* members of the Kreutz group, but you *can* also post Kreutz comets, perhaps that would be good too. Such an example would be [Comet Lovejoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C/2011_W3_(Lovejoy)).

Also welcome are posts on sungrazing comets that once were long-periodic but have changed to periodic due to another planet's gravity influence.

Thank you.

Comment: I think there should be tags on categories of comets, "comet" is quite broad. Such as non-periodic comets, long-periodic comets, periodic comets, interstellar asteroids/comets, sungrazing comets or Kreutz group. And perhaps Halley's Comet should get an own tag, maybe some other great comets too.